# How to recode a string to a numeric value in Stata?

Tags: replace, stata, recode

I am using the `replace` command to recode a string variable `countrycode` to a numeric variable `ccode`.

But the `replace` command has no effect. Stata gives no error messages, bt just says "0 changes made" after each line.

`countrycode` is a 3-character string.

This is the syntax:

```
gen ccode=-9
replace ccode=371 if countrycode=="arm"
replace ccode=900 if countrycode=="aus"
replace ccode=339 if countrycode=="alb"
replace ccode=160 if countrycode=="arg"
```

How can I convert the data to numeric?

Comment: The data are therefore not what you think or what you say.  Possibly there are leading or trailing spaces, other characters, or a clash of upper and lower case. Please consult the `stata` tag wiki for advice on giving a data example. What do `describe countrycode` and `codebook countrycode` say?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Describe countrycode says storage type: str3 and display format: %9s.  Codebook countrycode gives these examples of the data:

Comment: You were cut off in the middle of your comment.

Comment: There is no error in your code, but it might not match your data. For us to be able further we would need a reproducible example. See examples for how to do that using your real data or mock data here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info

Answer (score 0):

The code was correct, but the string variable was all caps, and I had used lower-case characters.  Thanks for the tip!